# Styling select dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am styling a select dropdown using jQuery. All works well except that the Selected option does not display as default. I have multiple dropdowns, each having its own default selection in a different position, on my page so I cannot define 1 particular postiion as selected. I'm trying to make the one with selected = "selected" to display by default.

Can you please help me with this?

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq().text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    //console.log($this.val());
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option selected="selected">Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: If you don't mind, why do you need to use jQuery for this not CSS? I recommend CSS rather than JS to do the stylings

Comment: i was also wanted to do with the css, but not getting desired styling. I'm not able to style dropdown. It showing browser specific dropdown. Is there a way style that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not targeting the correct element, using the following statement is

```
$styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq().text());
```

the method `.eq()` accept index of the element.

I think you need to get the `:selected` option's text, so use the selector.

```
$styledSelect.text($this.children('option:selected').text());
```

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option:selected').text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    //console.log($this.val());
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option selected="selected">Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```